# tsc can't find angular2 files

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript1.6

I'm trying out a sample angular2 app:

https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples

Folder structure:

[image]

When I run:

```
\angular-2-samples>tsc -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators --jsx react app.ts
```

everything is fine but when I run

```
\application\app\typescript>tsc -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata --expe
rimentalDecorators --jsx react app.ts
app.ts(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.
app.ts(2,51): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
app.ts(3,141): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
user/listen.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
user/listen.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
user/listen.ts(3,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
user/settings.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
user/settings.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
user/settings.ts(3,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
user/wishlist.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.
user/wishlist.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
user/wishlist.ts(3,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/router'.
```

We both have the same typings folder:

[image]

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: ever end up figuring out what the issue was?

Comment: I did get to a working version but I'm not sure what helped. I have midterms now so I'll post next week what is the update